# Am I required to disclose second nationality?

Tags: dual-citizenship, legal

Scenario:

I am a dual national of countries X and Y and I'm living in third country Z.

I've entered country Z on passport X.

If I'm asked about my nationality in general on documents (but no question directly refers to second nationality), am I obligated to say both X and Y, or may I disclose only one or the other?

If I'm explicitly asked 'do you hold a second nationality' am I obligated to disclose it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on the context in which you are asked about your nationality, and on the law of any jurisdiction that might apply to your filling out the form.  It's impossible to give a meaningful answer to this question for the general case.

Comment: As an example, suppose country Z is the US.  There, it would be illegal under [18 USC 1001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001) to conceal your second nationality from the Federal government, but only if it is "material."  In most cases, it won't be material, but in some cases it will be.  Therefore, you may or may not be obliged to disclose it.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on countries X and Z.

If country X discriminates against citizens of Z, then not telling that you are citizen of Z might have all kinds of negative consequences for you when found out.

If you are asked a direct question you have the choice to refuse an answer (which usually means your visa application is refused, or you are refused entry), you say the truth, or you lie which is usually worse than telling the truth if found out.

Comment: I think you've mixed up the variables here.  X and Y are the countries of nationality, while the person is present in Z and is filling out a form there.

Comment: @phoog You had it right in your comment to the earlier Answer. How the OP must answer is country-dependent, and could involve either of the countries in which citizenship is held, or the country of residence, or some combination of any of the three. The question is still not subject to answer in the general case.